# ¿Por qué mi código no entra en el controlador?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, php7

Tengo una ruta de tipo resource

```
Route::resource('cliente/compra', 'PedidoController');
```

A la que llamo por medio de

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=> 'cliente/compra', 'method'=> 'POST', 'autocomplete'=> 'off'))!!}
```

En mi vista create.blade.php

He de añadir que estoy usando JQuery para añadir los datos a una tabla que se va llenando por medio de este, el código es el siguiente:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn_add').click(function(evento){
                var button = evento.target;

                agregar($(button).attr("data-norden"));
            })
        });
function agregar(id)
        {

            var idlibro=$("#lped_libro_id"+ id).val();
            var libro=$("#lped_lib_titulo" + id).val();
            var cantidad=$("#lped_unidades" +id).val();
            var pvp=$("#lped_pvp" + id).val();


            if(idlibro!="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0 && libro!="") {

                var cambio=false;

                $(".idlibro").filter(function()
                {
                    if ($(this).val() == idlibro) {
                        console.log("encontrado");
                        var cantidad1=$("#cantidad" + id).val();
                        var subtotal1=$("#subtotal"+ id).val();
                        var cantidad2= parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(cantidad1);

                        var subtotal2=cantidad2*pvp + pvp*0.18*cantidad2;

                        $("#unidad"+id).remove();

                        var fila=$('<td id="unidad'+id+'"><input type="hidden" name="cantidad[]" value="' + cantidad2 + '" id="cantidad'+ id +'"></td>').text(cantidad2);
                        $("#despueslibro"+id).after(fila);

                        console.log($("#cantidad"+ id).html());
                        $("#subtotal"+ id).html(subtotal2);
                        subtotal[id]=subtotal2;
                        console.log(subtotal[id]);
                        cambio=true;
                        total=0;
                        for(var $j=1; $j<subtotal.length;$j++){

                            total+=subtotal[$j];
                        }
                    }

                });




                    if(cambio==false){
                        subtotal[id] = (cantidad * pvp + pvp * 0.18* cantidad);
                        total = total + subtotal[id];
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + id + '">' +
                            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar(' + id + ');">X</button>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="libro[]" value="' + libro + '"></td>' +
                            '<td><input type="hidden" name="ped_no[]" value="' + id + '">' + id + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="despueslibro'+id+'"><input type="hidden" class="idlibro" name="idlibro[]" value="' + idlibro + '">' + libro + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="unidad'+id+'"><input type="hidden" name="cantidad[]" value="' + cantidad + '" id="cantidad'+ id +'">' + cantidad + '</td>' +
                            '<td><input type="hidden" name="pvp[]" value="' + pvp + '">' + pvp + '</td>' +
                            '<td><input type="hidden" name="iva[]" value="' + 0.18 + '">18%</td>' +
                            '<td  id="subtotal'+ id +'">' + subtotal[id] + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';

                        $("#detalles").append(fila);
                    }


                        limpiar(id);
                        $("#total").html(total + " €");
                        evaluar();


            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error al ingresar detalle de ingreso");
            }
        }
```

Mis métodos en el controlador son index que me lleva a la vista create.blade.php y el método store que SUPUESTAMENTE es el que recoge todos los datos de la vista anteriormente nombrada. Pero cuando debugeo no entra nunca en el punto de ruptura de el código del método store anteriormente nombrado, ¿alguna idea de por qué pasa esto?

El código del método que recibe al formulario es:

```
public function store(PedidoFormRequest $request)
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $pedido= new Pedido;
            $pedido->ped_no=0;
            $fecha=Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');
            $pedido->ped_fecha=$fecha->toDateString();

        if(Input::has('ped_pagado'))
        {
            $pedido->ped_pagado=1;
        }else{
            $pedido->ped_pagado=0;
        }
        $pedido->ped_cliente_id=1;
        $pedido->ped_activo=1;
        $pedido->save();

        $pedidoid=DB::table('pedido')->orderBy('id_pedido', 'desc')
            ->first();
        $pedido2=Pedido::findOrFail($pedidoid->id_pedido);
        $pedido2->ped_no=$pedidoid->id_pedido+1;

        if(Input::has('ped_facturado'))
        {
            $pedidoid2=DB::table('pedido')->orderBy('id_pedido', 'desc')
                ->where('ped_facturado', '=', '1')
                ->first();

            $pedido2->ped_facturado=1;
            $pedido2->ped_fecha_factura=$fecha->toDateString();
            if($pedidoid2!=null) {
                $pedido2->ped_factura_id = $pedidoid2->id_pedido + 1;
            }else{
                $pedido2->ped_factura_id =1;
            }
        }else{

            $pedido2->ped_facturado=0;

        }
        $pedido2->update();

        $ped_no=$request->get('ped_no');
        $idlibro=$request->get('idlibro');
        $cantidad=$request->get('cantidad');
        $descripcion=$request->get('libro');
        $pvp=$request->get('pvp');

        $i=0;

        while($i< count($ped_no))
        {
            $lineaPedido= new LineaPedido();
            $lineaPedido->lpe_no=$ped_no[$i];
            $lineaPedido->lpe_descripcion=$descripcion[$i];
            $lineaPedido->lpe_unidades=$cantidad[$i];
            $lineaPedido->lpe_pvp=$pvp[$i];
            $lineaPedido->lpe_iva=18;
            $lineaPedido->lpe_pedido_id=$pedidoid->id_pedido;
            $lineaPedido->lpe_libro_id=$idlibro[$i];
            $lineaPedido->save();

            $i++;
        }

        DB::commit();

    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollback();
    }

    return Redirect::to('cliente/compra');
}
```

Comment: ¿qué error aparece? ¿cuál es el código del método que "recibe" al formulario?

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema Shaz es que no me sale ningún error, o no se donde verlo...

Comment: Para ver las rutas de tu proyecto usa `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: Deberías poder ver todo en el inspector de Chrome, a qué ruta esta llegando y qué respuesta estás recibiendo. Por cierto, no se recomienda utilizar las url directamente en Laravel, aprovecha el helper `route()`

Comment: He estado probándolo pero no me muestra ningún error, me sale como 302 found. ¿Puede ser quizás porque estoy usando el tipo de ruta resource cuando quiero enviar los datos que se recogen en la vista desde el método index?